# lcov and gcovr option for ignoring compiler generated dead code

Tags: c++, code-coverage, gcov, lcov, gcovr

My team is looking for a way to get around gcov reporting branch coverage for dead/compiler generated code. I noticed that gcovr has an option `--exclude-unreachable-branches` that seems to do what we need. Also, lcov has the option `--no-markers` which *Ignore[s] exclusion markers in source code*.

**Do these two options leave the compiler generated "dead code" out of the branch coverage?**

Also, I'm wondering,

**What is the difference between these two tools?**

We currently use lcov, and I know it displays gcov info in a graphical display format.